# Does cyclone perform static or dynamic checks on fat pointers?

Tags: c, static-analysis, bounds-checker

I am working my way thru [Cyclone: A Safe Dialect of C](http://www.cs.umd.edu/projects/cyclone/papers/cyclone-safety.pdf) for a PL class. The paper's authors explain that they've added a special 'fat' pointer that stores bounds information to prevent buffer overflows. But they don't specify if the check on this pointer is static or dynamic. The example they give seems to imply that the programmer must remember to check the size of the array in order to check that they don't exceed the buffer. This seems to open up the possibility of programming errors, just like in C. I thought the whole idea of Cyclone was to make such errors impossible. Does the language have a check? Does it just make it harder to make programming mistakes?

```
int strlen(const char ?s) {
    int i, n;
    if (!s) return 0;
    n = s.size; //what if the programmer forgets to do this.. or accidentally adds an n++;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++,s++)
         if (!*s) return i;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Its pretty hard to reason statically about C.  (Pascal Cuoq, who answered your questions, builds static analysis tools that do pretty well compared to most).  And for those things that static analysis tools cannot check, your only hope is a runtime check at the moment where the program might make a mistake.  Here's another paper on dynamic analysis that I think goes further than Cyclone: http://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/scam/2011/4347/00/4347a165-abs.html.  This paper uses "fat" pointers that are represented in several parts so as to not break C data structures by being the wrong size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Fat" pointers support pointer arithmetic with run-time bounds
>   checking.

Obtained from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclone_%28programming_language%29) by googling for “fat pointers”.